# Html form multiple field validation using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML form containing 4 number fields and one text field. I have written a validation code using JS as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {

    discount_threshold = document.myForm.discount_threshold.value;
    discountThreshold = document.myForm.discountThreshold.value;
    cpThreshold = document.myForm.cpThreshold.value;
    markdownCpThreshold = document.myForm.markdownCpThreshold.value;
    minInventoryThreshold = document.myForm.minInventoryThreshold.value;
    variationMode = document.myForm.variationMode.value;



   if (discount_threshold < 0 || discount_threshold > 100){
       window.alert("Please enter valid discount threshold between 0 to 100");
       discount_threshold.focus();
       return false;
   }
   if (cpThreshold < 0 || cpThreshold > 100){
       window.alert("Please enter valid CP threshold between 0 to 100");
       cpThreshold.focus();
       return false;
   }
   if (markdownCpThreshold < 0 || markdownCpThreshold > 100){
       window.alert("Please enter valid markdownCpThreshold threshold between 0 to 100");
       markdownCpThreshold.focus();
       return false;
   }
   if (minInventoryThreshold < 0 || minInventoryThreshold > 100){
       window.alert("Please enter valid minimum Inventory Threshold between 0 to 100");
       minInventoryThreshold.focus();
       return false;
   }
   if (variationMode !== "disabled" || variationMode !== "enabled"){
  window.alert("Please enter valid variation mode: disabled or enabled");
  variationMode.focus();
  return false;
}

}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Discount Threshold*: <input type="number" name="discount_threshold"> <br>
CP Threshold*: <input type="number" name="cpThreshold"> <br>
Markdown Threshold*: <input type="number" name="markdownCpThreshold"> <br>
Minimum Inventory*: <input type="number" name="minInventoryThreshold"> <br>
Variation Mode*: <input type="text" name="variationMode"> <br>

<button class="btn btn-primary" style="color:white !important; height:inherit; width:inherit;" type=submit>Save Configuration</button>
</form>
</body>
<html>
```

I am not expecting all the fields to be filled from user and hence accordingly I have put validations. When user doest not enter values in field 1 and then enter value beyond threshold value for field 3, I should have got alert for same. However, it is not happening as expected.

Comment: Did you hear about scopes in JS?

Comment: Not really. But just went through it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function validateForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const discount_threshold = e.target.elements.discount_threshold.value;
  const cpThreshold = document.myForm.cpThreshold.value;
  const markdownCpThreshold = e.target.elements.markdownCpThreshold.value;
  const minInventoryThreshold = e.target.elements.minInventoryThreshold.value;
  const variationMode = e.target.elements.variationMode.value;

  if (discount_threshold < 0 || discount_threshold > 100) {
    alert("Please enter valid discount threshold between 0 to 100");
    e.target.elements.discount_threshold.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (cpThreshold < 0 || cpThreshold > 100) {
    alert("Please enter valid CP threshold between 0 to 100");
    e.target.elements.cpThreshold.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (markdownCpThreshold < 0 || markdownCpThreshold > 100) {
    alert("Please enter valid markdownCpThreshold threshold between 0 to 100");
    e.target.elements.markdownCpThreshold.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (minInventoryThreshold < 0 || minInventoryThreshold > 100) {
    alert("Please enter valid minimum Inventory Threshold between 0 to 100");
    e.target.elements.minInventoryThreshold.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (variationMode !== "disabled" || variationMode !== "enabled") {
    alert("Please enter valid variation mode: disabled or enabled");
    e.target.elements.variationMode.focus();
    return false;
  }

}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="validateForm(event)" method="post">
  Discount Threshold*: <input type="number" name="discount_threshold"> <br> CP Threshold*: <input type="number" name="cpThreshold"> <br> Markdown Threshold*: <input type="number" name="markdownCpThreshold"> <br> Minimum Inventory*: <input type="number"
    name="minInventoryThreshold"> <br> Variation Mode*: <input type="text" name="variationMode"> <br>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" style="color:white; height:inherit; width:inherit;" type=submit>Save Configuration</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax issue. You closed the braces for validateForm function after getting value for "variationMode" variable and you are having closing brace for function after all if conditions ends. Try removing the closing brace after "variationMode" variable.

Comment: Apologies. While adding code here it got added. In actual code, function is closed properly. But still issue exists.

Comment: There is no "discountThreshold" field in the form but you are trying to get the value for undefined field in second line of "validateForm" method. Try commenting that line.